# filtering out rows across many columns in R

Tags: r

I have data with about 250 columns. A sample looks a bit like below:

| shop1_freq | shop1_enj | shop2_freq | shop2_enj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9 | 3 | 6 |
| 999 | 9 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 999 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 |

I want to remove rows (which represent participants) if they have "999" scored in *any* column because this represents an incorrect response. I have tried some simple code below, but this does not work.

```
data %>%
  filter_all(!= 999)
```

A score of 999 is only possible from about column 67 to 167, but I thought it would be easier to just specify in the code across all columns in the data.

Are there any better approaches to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ . != 999))
#    shop1_freq shop1_enj shop2_freq shop2_enj
#1          0         9          3         6 
#2          4         1          3         4
```

---

Or use `if_any` to check whether there are '999' in any of the column and negate (`!`)

```
data %>% 
   filter(!if_any(everything(), ~ . == 999))
```

---

Or using the OP's approach (which is kind of deprecated)

```
data %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(.!= 999))
#  shop1_freq shop1_enj shop2_freq shop2_enj
#1          0         9          3         6
#2          4         1          3         4
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rowSums` to construct a logical vector

```
data[rowSums(data == 999) == 0,]
```

Or `replace` the `999` with NA and use `na.omit`

```
na.omit(replace(data, data == 999, NA))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(shop1_freq = c(0L, 999L, 3L, 4L), shop1_enj = c(9L, 
9L, 2L, 1L), shop2_freq = c(3L, 2L, 999L, 3L), shop2_enj = c(6L, 
1L, 2L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you! The if_any produced the desired outcome. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(!any(c_across(everything()) == 999))
```

In `base R`:

```
df[-which(apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 999))), ]
```

or, even simpler:

```
df[!rowSums(df == 999) > 0,]
```